React project's build produces chunk files instead of usable output
I'm trying to create a build for a react typescript repository to later deploy on gcp for a class activity.
I'm using a public repo for this activity, out teacher chose it, (antoniopapa/react-ambassador), I did not code the project but I have taken a look at the code and the config files: package.json and tsconfig.json to check for any anomaly and they look fine.
When I run this project locally (npm run start) it works ok, I just had to add a flag to the package.json file, like this to get it to work:
    "start": "NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider PORT=4000 react-scripts start",
    "build": "NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider react-scripts build",

I added the same flag for the build command.
However, the output of the build is not usable, the files have chunk and other weird expressions in the name. Like this:
File sizes after gzip:

  59.89 KB  build/static/js/2.54961a9e.chunk.js
  3.56 KB   build/static/js/main.7356b288.chunk.js
  1.62 KB   build/static/js/3.1cb8c617.chunk.js
  1.18 KB   build/static/js/runtime-main.844da226.js
  290 B     build/static/css/main.b4945e2b.chunk.css

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /st/.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.

I have tried building a simple react typescript app and it worked fine. So I'm thinking it's not a problem with a path variable in my system or such.
All help is very much appreciated.
I tried taking off the flag I added to build it and it throws an error and doesn't build anything.
If I leave the flag on, it doesnt display any error (just the usual warnings) but it produces a broken build, the build can be run using serve -s build but it doesnt display any valid url, just an error message.
